# Deleting Duplicate Videos From Playlist

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I want to clean a public playlist I've created of duplicate, identical videos. I wrote the following script as a test but I'm getting a stubborn "access forbidden" error on line:9. I'm not sure what's causing it but I'm pretty sure I gave the script the required authorization to delete playlist items. I also made sure that PlaylistItems.list works fine and can access the playlist. I just keep getting stuck at PlaylistItems.remove

```
function main()
{
  var maxres = 1;
  var response = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list("snippet,contentDetails", {playlistId: "PLYtE-PC********_S8***************", maxResults: maxres});

  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(response.items[0].id);
  
  YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(response.items[0].id);
}
```

Error log:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.delete failed with error: Forbidden
main    @ Code.gs:9
```

An answer I got from another site said I need to check if the script has permission to delete videos. So I went to the Google Permission page ("Apps with access to your account"), confirmed that said app has access to my YouTube account. However, it doesn't specify if I can delete vids or not. I'm confused, is there a separate setting for this?!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete) the script should have these scopes added to it for the API to work properly:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

You can see the scopes your script project currently requires by doing the following:

1. Open the script project.
2. At the left, click **Overview**.
3. View the scopes under **Project OAuth Scopes**.

To add scopes manually you can modify the `appsscript.json` manifest file. You can check the reference page [Authorization Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) on how to do this.

Comment: I've managed to add all three scopes and I can now see them in the overview of my project. I am still getting the same exact error message from before

Comment: Same error occurs when trying to use the "Try this API" widget, given all three scopes, found in the documentation page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete